# Get month-day pair without a year from pandas date time

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I am trying to use this, but eventually, I get the same year-month-day format where my year changed to default "1900". I want to get only month-day pairs if it is possible.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m-%d")
```

Comment: kindly share your code to get better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you transform anything to date time, you'll always have a year in it, i.e. `to_datetime` will always yield a date time with a year.

Without a year, you will need to store it as a string, e.g. by running the inverse of your example:

```py
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime(format="%m-%d")
```

Comment: It is pity that we cannot have a datetime format without a year, thank you.